# Android: list mounted volumes

Tags: java, android, file, root, mount

how can I get a list of all mounted volumes on an Android device? I want then to fetch the result in a String[] array. Of course I'm using Java.
(or, is it possible without root to get the contents of the /mnt did?)
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Different android versions and different android devices mount storage volumes differently. You cannot always expect the sdcard for example to always be in the "/mnt" folder. To get the External Storage directly you can use the method, "Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory". This will provide you with the sdcard directory if mounted, otherwise this will return the path for internal storage.

Comment: This does not really works, since getExternalStorageDirectory does not always get the external storage directory, but the internal one. Read the `Note` here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()